# How to implement Google GeoCharts with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, google-maps

You can find the Google GeoChart code example and docs here https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

I know that if I copy and paste this two script files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages':['geochart'],
        // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
        // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
        'mapsApiKey': 'MY_API_KEY'
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Popularity'],
          ['Germany', 200],
          ['United States', 300],
          ['Brazil', 400],
          ['Canada', 500],
          ['France', 600],
          ['RU', 700]
        ]);

        var options = {};

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

within my `<head>` tag in the main `index.html` (where the `<app-root>` lives) I'll get the expected output... The map with all that dummy data

[image]

Instead all that dummy data, I want to inject some other countries and values, but as soon as I place all that code and methods in another JS file, the GeoMap doesnt show up anymore on the screen

Current `index.html` file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Covid19</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Google Geomaps -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./geomaps.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Current `geomaps.js` file:

```
google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['geochart'],
      // Google Api Key
      'mapsApiKey': ''
      // MY_API_KEY
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

    function drawRegionsMap() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Country', 'Popularity'],
        ['Germany', 200],
        ['United States', 300],
        ['Brazil', 400],
        ['Canada', 500],
        ['France', 600],
        ['RU', 700]
      ]);

      var options = {};

      var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
```

Output on the screen: Nothing

Output on the chrome dev tools console:
[image]

Comment: I've removed your API key from your answer. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 0):

This one is without using angular, you can make changes in the javascript and HTML file as per requirement.

I tried with the existing example available here [Visualization: Geomap](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geomap#examples)

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Covid19</title>
    <base href=".">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Google Geomaps -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="geomaps.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

geomaps.js

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages':['geochart'],
  // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
  // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load- 
settings
  'mapsApiKey': 'MY_API_KEY'
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Country', 'Popularity'],
  ['Germany', 200],
  ['United States', 300],
  ['Brazil', 400],
  ['Canada', 500],
  ['France', 600],
  ['RU', 700]
]);

var options = {};

var chart = new 
google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

favicon.ico: created one and put all files at the same location

You missed one "}" in the javascript file geomaps.js.

src="geomaps.js" for the current directory.

`<base href="/">` Specifies the base URL which will be used for all relative links in the current document. I replaced it with `<base href=".">` as I have put all the files in the same folder.

I got the response without any error.
[Chrome output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7zfW.png)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put within the `assets` folder the `geomaps.js` file

I end up having the index.html file like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Google Geomaps -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/geomaps.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

and my `geomaps.js` file like this:

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages':['geochart'],
  // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
  // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load- 
settings
  'mapsApiKey': 'your-api-key'
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Country', 'Popularity'],
  ['Germany', 200],
  ['United States', 300],
  ['Brazil', 400],
  ['Canada', 500],
  ['France', 600],
  ['RU', 700]
]);

var options = {};

var chart = new 
google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Just like in the beginning, the difference is that I had to put the geomaps.js file in the `assets` folder

**Solution for Angular**